# Is there a way to display a google maps with a route from a Facebook app without needing a backend?

Tags: facebook, maps, routes

So I've got a mobile app that tracks a user's route. (cycling app.) I'd like to create a Facebook app that I can use to display their route on Facebook. Is this possible to do without requiring a backend server of my own? I've heard it's possible, but given that I'm uploading 500-700k worth of route data at times, I'm not exactly sure how that could possibly work. Any pointers?

Thanks!